# Relate an HTML table click event to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, handler, dom-manipulation

Looking to implement a game here, and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do it.

(This will be **Tic-Tac-Toe** expanded greatly).

**Theoretically, if I have a multidimensional array in JS:**

ie: `var array = [ ["","",""], ["","",""], ["","",""] ]`

**And an HTML table for example:**

```
<table id="board">
  <tr>
   <td>""</td><td>""</td><td>""</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>""</td><td>""</td><td>""</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>""</td><td>""</td><td>""</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**How would I apply a click handler to the table to reference the indexed values in the array I have built?**

For example,

`array[1][1]` should be equal to the 2nd child `tr` of the table, and the 2nd child `td` of the selected (or the technical middle square once I apply some CSS).

So, I need my click event to select your spot on the table to convert our array to...

`array = [ ["","",""], ["","X",""], ["","",""] ]`

I know it should be pretty simple. I already have the computer action working for selecting locations randomly, but I need the user input part and I'm brain farting.

**(I'm OK to use `jQuery` for this functionality if its easier)**
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Getting somewhere.... Why doesn't this append?
http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `tableElement.rows[1].cells[1]` to get the xell at coordinates 1,1 from the top-left.  You can then do anything you'd normally want to do with that.

You can also bind the event to the table, and then do `[event.target.cellIndex, event.target.parentNode.rowIndex]` to get the coordinates x,y within that event listener.

Comment: Perfect. I was having trouble finding the correct syntax to use for it. Thanks! I'll play around with your answer.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I've also added something extra for if you need to get the coordinates from the cell element, so basically the code to do it the exact other way around.

Comment: THAT is the answer I was looking for. Marking as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("tr:eq(x)  td:eq(y)").text();
```

Put your row and col for x and y

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do something like:

```
var rows = $('#board tr');
```

You can access that like an array: `$(rows[2])` for the third row, etc.

To get the columns in a row, you can use jQuery's child queries:

```
var cols = $('td', rows[2]);
```

Note: if jQuery is in no conflict mode, you'll need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`or wrap it all in a jQuery closure.